# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Tags: php, function, post, exec, fatal-error

I have a pretty nasty error I can't get rid of. Here's the function causing the issue:

```
    function get_info_by_WatIAM($WatIAM, $info) { 
    $users_info = array();
    exec("uwdir -v userid={$WatIAM}", $users_info);
    foreach ($users_info as $user_info) {
        $exploded_info = explode(":", $user_info);
        if (isset($exploded_info[1])){              
            $infoArray[$exploded_info[0]] = $exploded_info[1];
        } 
    }
    return $infoArray[$info];   }
```

Here's what's calling the function:

```
} elseif (  empty(get_info_by_WatIAM($_POST['ownerId'])) ) { ...
```

I would really appreciate any suggestion. Thanks very much!

If the code doesn't make sense, here's a further explanation: exec uses a program that stores information on all the users in a school. These include things like faculty, name, userid, etc. The `$_POST['ownerId']` is a username -- the idea is that, upon entering a username, all of the user's information is automatically filled in

Comment: When including inline code in your posts on SO, always enclose in backticks (`) so it is properly highlighted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need `empty` around function calls, in fact `empty` only works with variables and not functions (as you see). You only need `empty` if you want to test a variable *that may not be set* for *thruthiness*. It is pointless around a function call, since that function call must exist. Instead simply use:

```
} else if (!get_info_by_WatIAM($_POST['ownerId'])) { ...
```

It does the same thing. For an in-depth explanation, read [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/).

Comment: You're very right -- fixed it! Great explanation, thanks very much deceze

Answer (score 3):

[`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) can only be used on variables, not on expressions (such as the result of calling a function). There's a warning on the documentation page:

> Note:
>
> `empty()` only checks variables as anything else will result in a parse
>   error. In other words, the following will not work: `empty(trim($name))`.

Just one of PHP's best-left-alone quirks.

One workaround is to store the result in a variable and call `empty` on that, although it's clunky. In *this specific case*, you can also use

```
if (!get_info_by_WatIAM(...))
```

...although in general, `if (empty($a))` and `if(!$a)` are not equivalent.

Comment: @deceze: No worries. But it's not a good idea IMHO to present the `!` alternative without an explicit warning that it's not equivalent.

Comment: Sure, they're not equivalent when talking about *variables*. `empty` does not trigger an error should the variable not exist. Otherwise they do exactly the same thing. As for *function calls*, `empty` is simply not applicable at all.

Comment: Thanks Jon, great answer. I used ! in front of the function and that fixed it. Sadly, deceze beat you to it!

Answer (score -1):

get the value of this

```
$a = get_info_by_WatIAM($_POST['ownerId'])
```

then chack

```
empty($a)
```

it will work